# add new column based on mutual value in 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:

df1:

[image]

and df2:

[image]

They have differnet size. The common parts between these dataframes is the columns `B` (df1) and `Z` (df2), and based on columns `B` and `Z` I want to obtain new dataframe:

[image]

That add the major of student that are common between df1 and df2 and if it doesn't exist in df2 have empty value.

Comment: Please add your data frame in code for for better assistance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 1):

You can `merge` the two dataframes on the `B` and `Z` columns, e.g.:

```py
df = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, left_on='B', right_on='Z', how='left')
```

Comment: I think you need `how='left'`, otherwise B=85 and B=12 will be missing in the result, won't they?